# Python: frame parameter of signal handler

Tags: python, signals

I was looking through the Python documentation for signal and in the example code:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    raise IOError("Couldn't open device!")
```

The 'frame' parameter is not used in the actual function. I noticed this in a lot of code on stackoverflow/online regarding signal handlers. What is the 'frame' parameter? Why is it kept in the function header?

Thank you

Answer (score 26):

The frame argument is the stack frame, also known as execution frame. It point to the frame that was interrupted by the signal. The parameter is required because any thread might be interrupted by a signal, but the signal is only received in the main thread.

Example:

```
import signal
import os
import traceback

def handler(signum, frame):
    print signum, frame
    print "print stack frames:"
    traceback.print_stack(frame)

def demo(n):
    if n == 3:
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
        return
    demo(n+1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
demo(1)
```

Output:

```
$ python t.py
10 <frame object at 0x1e00520>
print stack frames:
  File "t.py", line 17, in <module>
    demo(1)
  File "t.py", line 14, in demo
    demo(n+1)
  File "t.py", line 14, in demo
    demo(n+1)
  File "t.py", line 12, in demo
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Comment: Great example - should be part of the documentation

Comment: Shouldn't we use Exception under handler?

Answer (score 6):

The frame parameter is a [Python stack frame](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal). Excerpted from the manual:

> The handler is called with two arguments: the signal number and the current stack frame (None or a frame object; for a description of frame objects, see the description in the type hierarchy or see the attribute descriptions in the inspect module).

It is often ignored in the examples you see because it isn't particularly useful outside of a Python debugger. Signals are asynchronous and hit a process willy-nilly. If I send SIGTERM to your process and you've set up to handle it, where your code was when it received the signal is usually irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

It's the current [stack frame](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects).

For example it can be useful to print the current stack information before aborting on some signals.

Comment: ok but what is its type in mypy?